# Detecting periodicity in point processes

Tags: statistics, signal-processing

I have  data from a periodic one dimensional point process representing the times of events which is also mixed in with lots of data that I regard as noise.  The total number of points is of order one million. I would like to detect (approximate) periodicity in the data to reconstruct the periodic point precess.   This question is a little vague but what is a good method for doing this?

As an example, if my points are $1,10,25,30,31,50$ I would like to detect $10, 30, 50$ as equally spaced points.  As my values are reals I need this to tolerate small errors in the data.

Comment: A few questions: How large is is "large" in your case? Are we talking about tens, thousands, millions of data-points? If I understood correctly, you're looking for a sub-sequence of your sequence of numbers such that the differences between successive terms are "almost" constant. What if there are multiple such sub-sequences? Are you looking for the longest one; the one with smallest variation in the difference (which might be a very short one!) or do you have some other criteria for the desired one?

Comment: @PeterKošinár We are talking a million. You are right that I am looking for a (not necessarily consecutive) sub-sequence of my sequence of numbers such that the differences between successive terms are "almost" constant.  I would be happy to set a minimum "length" so that the subsequence has to have at least $k$ points in it. If there are multiple of that length or longer it would be great if I could list them all or really even some of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are pulse trains in noise. The pulse train is its own Fourier transform (sort of) and noise (usually) is spread out evenly in the frequency domain.

1. Make vector of all zeros. Call it x.
2. For each time value, set that index of x to 1. For instance, if your points are 1,10,25,30,31,50, then set x(1)=1, x(10)=1, x(25)=1, and so on.
3. Take the DFT of this sequence and plot it's amplitude.
4. There will be a series of regularly-spaced spikes corresponding to the periodic components of the input. Their spacing will be the reciprocal of the period in the time domain.

Here's is a quick and dirty example I put together in Matlab:

```
N = 1e6;
x = zeros(N,1);
x(1:33:end) = 1;             % Pulse train 1.
x(1:137:end) = 1;            % Pulse train 2.
randinds = randperm(N);      % Random permutation for noise.
x(randinds(1:10e4)) = 1;     % Add some noise points.
X = fftshift( fft( x ) );
f = (-0.5:1/N:0.5-1/N);
plot( f, abs( X ) );
```

There are two series of pulse trains visible in the plot of the magnitude of the FT of x. By visual inspection, one is spaced at 0.0303 and the other at 7.299e-3, which gives time domain periods of 33.0033 and 137.005, respectively.

You may have to tailor the above to your exact situation, but I think something along these lines is doable and easy to implement.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that if the times of the events are separated by millions then the vector of zeros in step 1 will be very very long.   Is there some possibly approximate way of making the computation time depend on the number of non-zero values?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it, since you if use four-byte floats (which should be enough accuracy) you get 250 million elements before you hit 1GB of memory. As for the computation time, I wouldn't about worry that either until you find that it is a problem (fft routines are pretty fast). If you have real-time constraints, that is another can of worms. Most environments also provide support for sparse vectors (I know Matlab does) and you can look into that if you want/need to. Again though, I wouldn't spend the time on such until you are sure that it is necessary.

Comment: @marshall Also, you could downsample your data if needed. Something like the following would cut the size of your input by a factor of $n$: $y(i)=\operatorname{max}(x(j))$ for $j=n\cdot i, \dots, (n+1)\cdot i$, $i=0,1,2,\dots$. Just the multiply the answer by $n$ and you will get the correct value. It's possible there will be a slight loss in the accuracy of your estimate, but you might have to accept the trade-off.